# when register, insert data in 3 tables LARAVEL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I work at a project, I started to learn Laravel and I wanted to create a register form where you can put all your information and all the information to be sent in 3 tables.

You have to select if you are a candidate or a employer. 
In my database i have those 3 tables: `users`, `profile_employee` and `profile_employer`.

Can someone show me how to create the `RegisterController` to insert in the table users only email and password, and if they selected candidate to send the rest of information to `profile_employee`, and if they selected employer to send them to the table `profile_employer`. Thanks!

This is are my models for `ProfilasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdeEmployeer` and `ProfileEmployee`

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProfileEmployee extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'profasdasdasdasdile_emploasdasdasdasdyee';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id','usasdasdasder_id', 'fiasdasdasdasdasdst_name', 'laasdasdst_namasdasdasdasdasde','phonasdasdasde', 'casdasdv', 'picasdasdasdasdture', 'adrasdasdasdasdasdess', 'toasdasdasdasdasdasdwn',
    ];
    protected $hidasdasdasdasdasdden = [];
}
```

and

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProfileEmployer extends Model
{
    protected $tablasdasdasdasde = 'profileasdasdasdasdasdasdasd_emplasdasdasdasdasdasdoyer';
    protected $fillabasdasdasdasdle = [
        'iasdasdasdd','useasdasdr_iasdasdasdasdasdasd', 'coasdasdasdasdasdmpany_naasdasdasdasdasdme', 'CasdasdasdU_asdasdI', 'phoasdasdasdasdasdne', 'pictasdasdasdasdasdure', 'adasdasdasdasdress', 'towasdasdasdasdasdn',
    ];
    protected $hidasdasdasdden = [];
}
```

How can I do the `RegistasdasdasdasdasdasdasderController`?

Answer (score 1):

Without writing any code I think the best way would be to create a polymorphic relationship, there’s some example code in the documentation-
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations

So in your users table you’d have a userable_type and userable_id (not sure if them names are correct). The userable_type column would contain the model name for either your ProfileEmployee table or your ProfileEmployer table and the userable_id the  foreign key of the relationship.

As you can see in the documentation you can then retrieve the relationship and laravel will know which model to use by the userable_type column.

Looking at your tables though I think you could merge the profiles into one table and maybe have a metadata column for data which isn’t always stored for both user types.

Comment: nice idea and methods there 

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by creating two separate method for user type to create them by passing user instance in `RegisterControlle` just like as follow. and dont forget to return user after creating profile.

```
class RegisterController extends Controller{

use RegistersUsers;

protected $redirectTo = '/home';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'type' => 'required|in:employee,employer',
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
    // check the user type
    $data['type'] = 'employee' ? $this->createEmployee($user) : $this->createEmployer($user);
}

public function createEmployee($user)
{
    // here you can create Employee profile

    return $user;
}

 public function createEmployer($user)
 {
    // here you can create Employer profile

    return $user;
 }
}
```

Here we need to overwrite two method which is `validator` and `create`.